# How to stop insert into after refreshing a page

Tags: php, sql, post, insert, page-refresh

How can I stop a insert into query after refreshing a page, after the post is done, so it won't put in all the post variables again after a refresh?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a header <(*make sure you're not outputting before header*). Use sessions and tokens.... too many ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the data has been inserted to the database, redirect and exit.

```
header('location: thepage.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your query look like this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
from somesmalltable 
where not exists
(subquery to check for existing records)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set a session variable and update it once the query has been written, if the value = 1 then dont execute the query again

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can solve it:

1. before inserting into the Database, check if the record already exist(I hope you have a primary key on the table so you can use this one)
2. You can set a session variable in your code after inserting into the DB. After reloading, you have to check if you have set the session-variable. If yes, you can skip the inserting. If no, you can insert into DB